# Function that returns all sub-sequences in a list that are successive

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have this function

```
def conseq_sequences(li, length):
    """ Takes a list and a length. Returns all sub-sequences in li that
    are successice (e.g. [1,2,3] or [5,6,7,8]) and of the right length.

    E.g.  >>> conseq_sequences([1,6,7,8,9,8,9], length=3)
          [[6,7,8], [7,8,9]]
    """
    return [li[n:n + length] for n in range(len(li) - length + 1)
            if li[n:n + length] == range(li[n], li[n] + length)]
```

This function is present in a class, and I can not understand way it does not work. When I invoke it, I get an empty sequence.

```
>>> conseq_sequences([1,6,7,8,9,8,9], length=3)
[]
```

Can someone help to make the modification in it in order to return all sub-sequences in list that are successive, as in the example?

Comment: `and I can not understand way it does not work` - what do you mean by that?

Comment: When i make: conseq_sequences([1,6,7,8,9,8,9], length=3), it return: [ ]

Comment: I get `[[6, 7, 8], [7, 8, 9]]` as expected.

Comment: @ thefourtheye I use python 3.4

Comment: What did you do?  thefourtheye

Comment: Then why did you tag Python 2.7?

Comment: I updated it for python3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3.x, [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) doesn't return a list, but a range object.

```
>>> range(1, 10)
range(1, 10)
>>> type(range(1, 10))
<class 'range'>
>>> [1, 2, 3] == range(1, 4)
False
>>> [1, 2, 3] == list(range(1, 4))
True
```

So, you need to explicitly convert that to a list, and then compare, like this

```
[li[n:n + length] for n in range(len(li) - length + 1)
    if li[n:n + length] == list(range(li[n], li[n] + length))]
```

Here, we create a new list, by converting the range object to a list, with

```
list(range(li[n], li[n] + length))
```

**Demo**

```
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def conseq_sequences(li, length):
...     """ Takes a list and a length. Returns all sub-sequences in li that
...     are successice (e.g. [1,2,3] or [5,6,7,8]) and of the right length.
... 
...     E.g.  >>> conseq_sequences([1,6,7,8,9,8,9], length=3)
...           [[6,7,8], [7,8,9]]
...     """
...     return [li[n:n + length] for n in range(len(li) - length + 1)
...             if li[n:n + length] == list(range(li[n], li[n] + length))]
... 
>>> conseq_sequences([1, 6, 7, 8, 9, 8, 9], 3)
[[6, 7, 8], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: only one question #thefourtheye: Why we did not create a list in [for n in range(len(li) - length + 1)]

Comment: Because we are just iterating the range object there. When we compare a list object to another object, that also has to be a list object. That is why we are converting only during the comparison.

Comment: Can I ask one more thing,  #thefourtheye? If a have a class written in python2, should I convert all the range objects in a list?

Comment: @user3573552 Nope. If you are just iterating a `range`, then you don't have to. You should convert that to a list, only when you want that to be treated as a list. Otherwise, `range` object is enough for most of the cases.